# Clickable map image to select an province

Tags: android, image, dictionary, ontouchlistener, clickable

I have a image of a Dutch map, now I want to click on a province and then go to the next screen. To give you an [idea](http://irishpubs.nl/index.php?lang=0&page=1):

I have searched on Google and Stackoverflow and read something about 'OnTouchListener'...

I need it for a android app..

Can someone help me with a start?

Comment: I've tried to take an image of each province and add them with a Imagebutton.. This looks not nice and i tink there is a much better way to do it..
Like i said something with a OnTouchListener ??
Can someone helm me?